# VirtualBox Windows x64 Error 0xc000035a

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
1) Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2) Choose your language settings, and then click 'Next."
3) Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact admin... bla bla bal.

File: \windows\system32\boot\winload.exe
Status: 0xc000035a
Info: Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode.
```

I get this error when i try to install Windows server 2008 x64 via VirtualBox.

I have All Virtual settings enabled in BIOS and my CPU is an Cor i5 vPro, the host system is Windows 7 x64.

[Youtube Screen casting of the error](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpgecSJXRbI)

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it is not a programming question. It's an operating system question, and is more suitable for [su] instead. However, it's almost always useful to **actually read the words** in the error message; in this case, the very last line (in fact, the last **8 words**) you quoted is extremely clear as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok but i have a core i5 CPU 8 cores

Comment: It's the CPU being emulated in the VM, not the actual physical CPU installed in your computer. Windows is not being installed on your computer; it's being installed in the virtual machine. If that's not clear to you, I think you should do some major research to understand what a virtual machine is and how it works. (Regardless, this question is still inappropriate for StackOverflow.)

Comment: Ken, i know what is virtualization, i was just trying to get help. I noticed that this is not in the right place.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and found a solution.

1. Open up bios and make sure vt-x is enabled
2. If it wasnt, you'll need to delete the VM in virtual box and make a new one.. Now you will see an option for windows 7 and windows 7 (64bit).

It was only AFTER i delete and rebuilt the VM did it allow me through.  Changing the settings in the existing VM didnt seem to do the trick.

Comment: Changing the existing setting for the VM did the trick for me